# Catching a NULL or Zero result in a MySQL WHEN statement searching for a Range

Tags: mysql, database, null

I am trying to extract sales of products from my database by price range.

I have a fairly complex SQL query, which works:

```
SELECT 
    SUM((t.price-t.discount)*t.quantity) as totalValue, 
    MAX(t.price) as maxP, 
    t.range AS score_range,  
    COUNT(*) AS count  
        FROM 
            (SELECT products.price, 
            salesRecords.discount,
            salesRecords.quantity,  
                CASE WHEN products.price >=0 AND products.price <50 THEN  '0-49' 
                WHEN products.price >=50 AND products.price <100 THEN  '50-99' 
                WHEN products.price >=100 AND products.price <200 THEN  '100-199' 
                WHEN products.price >=200 AND products.price <350 THEN  '200-349' 
                WHEN products.price >=200 AND products.price <350 THEN  '200-349'  
                WHEN products.price >=350 AND products.price <500 THEN  '350-499' 
                WHEN products.price >=500 AND products.price <800 THEN  '500-799' 
                WHEN products.price >=800 AND products.price <1200 THEN  '800-1199' 
                WHEN products.price >=1200 AND products.price <1800 THEN  '1200-1799' 
                WHEN products.price >=1800 AND products.price <2500 THEN  '1800-2499' 
                ELSE '2500 +' END 
            AS  range  FROM salesRecords 
                LEFT JOIN products ON products.id=salesRecords.itemNo 
                ORDER BY products.price DESC)t 
    GROUP BY t.range 
    ORDER BY maxP DESC
```

Hopefully, you can see what's going on here. We're grouping products within price ranges, summing the sales values and therefore getting an output like this:

```
totalValue  maxP         score_range    count   
8381    251.17       200-349        35
32522   199.00       100-199        198
22614   99.95        50-99      271
41825   49.99        0-49       2765
```

However, as you can see, with this particular dataset, there's a number of gaps.

I have values only for `score_range`s `200-349, 100-199,50-99, 0-49` missing any data for 35-499, 500-799 etc. This is because there is no data for those values... which is fine... except... I am injecting this data as a JSON object into an `AmCharts` Radar Chart and in order for the data to truly make sense for my application, I need to have all the ranges, and simply populate them with `zeros`, so what I want to get is:

```
totalValue  maxP     score_range    count   
0       3500         2500 +             0
0       2499         1800-2499          0
0       1799         1200-1799          0
0       1199         800-1199           0
0       799          500-799            0
0       499          350-499            0
8381    251.17       200-349            35
32522   199.00       100-199            198
22614   99.95        50-99              271
41825   49.99        0-49               2765
```

Comment: sql cannot generate data that isn't there to begin with. You could create a temp table listing each of those score ranges and somehow join it against your actual results. that'd give you the "missing" ranges with some zero/null results for them.

Answer (score 0):

You need a driving table so you have all ranges.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT tsum.totalValue, 
       maxP, 
       range.range AS score_range,  
       coalesce(count, 0) count  
FROM (select '0-49' as range union all
      select '50-99' union all
      . . .
     ) as range left outer join
     (SELECT SUM((t.price-t.discount)*t.quantity) as totalValue, 
             MAX(t.price) as maxP, 
             t.range AS score_range,  
             COUNT(*) AS count
      from (SELECT products.price, 
                   salesRecords.discount,
                   salesRecords.quantity,  
                   (CASE WHEN products.price >=0 AND products.price <50 THEN  '0-49' 
                         WHEN products.price >=50 AND products.price <100 THEN  '50-99' 
                         WHEN products.price >=100 AND products.price <200 THEN  '100-199' 
                         WHEN products.price >=200 AND products.price <350 THEN  '200-349' 
                         WHEN products.price >=200 AND products.price <350 THEN  '200-349'  
                         WHEN products.price >=350 AND products.price <500 THEN  '350-499' 
                         WHEN products.price >=500 AND products.price <800 THEN  '500-799' 
                         WHEN products.price >=800 AND products.price <1200 THEN  '800-1199' 
                         WHEN products.price >=1200 AND products.price <1800 THEN  '1200-1799' 
                         WHEN products.price >=1800 AND products.price <2500 THEN  '1800-2499' 
                         ELSE '2500 +'
                    END) AS  range
            FROM salesRecords LEFT JOIN
                 products
                 ON products.id=salesRecords.itemNo 
           )t
     ) tsum
     on ranges.range = tsum.score_range
GROUP BY ranges.range 
ORDER BY maxP DESC
```

However, this example suggests that you really wand to have a Ranges table, with the limits for the range defined.  Then you can do the whole case statement as a join.

Comment: That's interesting. I'd be happy to have a ranges table. Would those joins work in MySql though?

Comment: Yes.  The "on" condition would be a non-equijoin, requiring a full table scan.  However, the table would be small so the performance should not be that much worse than the case statement.

Comment: Reading this on my iPad now so I can't try it, but I'll investigate tomorrow. your example doesn't look right to me for MySql, but I'm a quite new effectively using table joins, so I'll reserve judgement til I've tried it!!